# Why am I not getting actual selected values in combobox?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I have two combo boxes `cmbfrom` and `cmbdest`..

The code for retrieving data from SQL database and setting it into combobox values is this:

```
databaseserver ser = new databaseserver();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ser.dbserver + "Initial Catalog=AirlinesDB;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open(); 
SqlDataAdapter citiesadp = new SqlDataAdapter("select city from cities",con);
DataSet dset = new DataSet(); //Creating instance of DataSet
citiesadp.Fill(dset,"cities");
cmbfrom.DataSource = dset.Tables["cities"];
cmbfrom.DisplayMember = "city";
con.Close();

SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ser.dbserver + "Initial Catalog=AirlinesDB;Integrated Security=True");
con1.Open();
SqlDataAdapter destcity = new SqlDataAdapter("select city from cities",con1);
DataSet destset = new DataSet();
destcity.Fill(destset,"cities");
cmbdest.DataSource = destset.Tables["cities"];
cmbdest.DisplayMember = "city";
con1.Close();
```

But when I select a value in `cmbdest`, it returns me `System.Data.DataRowView`, instead of the actual value.

The code for retrieving selected values from comboboxes is the following:

```
textBox1.Text = cmbdest.SelectedValue.ToString();
textBox2.Text = cmbfrom.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I get the actual value from first combo that is the selected city name, but the second one gets the value: `System.Data.DataRowView`.

Comment: try select `cmbfrom` and then what happens? is then 'cmbdest''s value is `System.Data.DataRowView.`?

Comment: No .. They get actual city name in combobox like dubai,mumbai,la etc same as cmbfrom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code below:

```
    databaseserver ser = new databaseserver();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ser.dbserver + "Initial Catalog=AirlinesDB;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open(); 
    SqlDataAdapter citiesadp = new SqlDataAdapter("select city from cities",con);
    DataSet dset = new DataSet(); //Creating instance of DataSet
    citiesadp.Fill(dset,"cities");
    cmbfrom.DataSource = dset.Tables["cities"];
    cmbfrom.DisplayMember = "city";
    cmbfrom..ValueMember= "city";

    con.Close();

    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ser.dbserver + "Initial Catalog=AirlinesDB;Integrated Security=True");
    con1.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter destcity = new SqlDataAdapter("select city from cities",con1);
    DataSet destset = new DataSet();
    destcity.Fill(destset,"cities");
    cmbdest.DataSource = destset.Tables["cities"];
    cmbdest.DisplayMember = "city";
    cmbdest..ValueMember= "city";
    con1.Close();
```

Comment: Please avoid the "try this" form. Instead, explain why the OP should follow your suggestion and the reason of his issue. Correct your code, it has some errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should first set the property `ValueMember` for the `cmbfrom`

Comment: What ? didn't understood what you said ?

Comment: I have no problems with cmbfrom its works the problem is with cmbdest

Comment: see the answer of Abdur Rahim above